# Why str("").strip() in (".32") is True in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I've developed a habit of searching within collections to verify the existence of elements as part of my conditions. Recently, I encountered a test case that necessitated this approach, but I found myself unable to provide a clear explanation for the observed behavior or outcome.

Why `str("").strip() in (".32") => True`

`print(str("").strip() in (".32"))`

But `str("").strip() in [".32"] => False`

It seems be something with the tuple, but I don't know why...

Comment: Yes, `... in (".32",)` would also be `False`

Comment: Think about using set literals -- `{".32"}` doesn't require a comma to be valid.

Comment: The [Immutable sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#immutable-sequences) doc has a bit of an explainer on Tuples

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(".32")` is not a tuple: it's a parenthesized string. `(".32",)` is a tuple. The comma makes the tuple, not the parentheses.

`str("").strip()` is an empty string. The empty string is not in the list `[".32"]` (nor is it in the tuple `(".32", )`).

It is, however, in the string `".32"`; the parentheses don't matter for this: `".32" == (".32")`.

Comment: You could even trim it down to `".32",` makes the tuple.